# UPDATE operation - Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object (VS2010 and Linq)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, null

WE have tow tables. one call **VirtualMachine** with column called ***sessionID***  that it foreign key to the second table that call **session** that have primary key called ***Id***    ( null-able `int`).

we using **linq to sql** and when we try to updated VirtualMachine.sessionID to `null` we got the following error

> "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"

our code:

```
List<VirtualMachine> currentVms = _context.getAllVMs();
foreach (VirtualMachine vm in currentVms)
{
    if (vm.sessionID != null)
    {
        //if no  change the session status 
        Session ChangeStatus = _context.getSessionByID((int)vm.sessionID);

        ChangeStatus.status = (int)sessionStatus.closed;
        _context.updateSesion(ChangeStatus);
        string SessionKey = vm.Session.sessionNumber;

        // change the session id to null
          VirtualMachine toUpdate = new VirtualMachine();
          toUpdate.ID = vm.ID;
          toUpdate.IP = vm.IP;
          toUpdate.sessionID = null;
          _context.updateVM(toUpdate);///here we get the exception.

    }
}
```

Comment: What are these `updateSession` and `updateVM` methods?

Comment: Is this really `LINQ2SQL`? I highly doubt it.

Comment: I think it because you change the foriegnKey. You have to change the value in the table 'session' and then assign the value to the 'VirtualMachine' table